# Running sphinx-quickstart from command line hangs on windows

Tags: python, windows, python-sphinx

I'm having a strange problem with sphinx-quickstart. Everything was working fine, but I decided to upgrade all my packages since I wasn't able to get iPython3 notebooks to render properly (with syntax highlighting and nbsphinx). I did this using the `pip install sphinx --upgrade` command.

Since then, my sphinx has been broken. I can run sphinx-quickstart and sphinx-build from the command window, but it hangs with no output. Strangely, if I navigate to the folder and execute sphinx-quickstart directly, it opens fine with correct output.

In addition if I type out the whole path "C:\Users\XX\Anaconda3\Scripts\sphinx-quickstart" it runs fine.

I'm not sure what kind of problem would cause this behavior...

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled anaconda and it seemed to solve the problem..I'm not sure if it is something to do with the upgraded version.